# Создание проекта в Django

Tags: python, django, eclipse, project

При создании проекта Django в Eclipse создается 3 вложенных папки с одинаковым именем, а команда django-admin.py startproject mysite в командной строке Windows создает 2 вложенных папки с одинаковым именем. Разве не должна создаваться только 1 папка?

Comment: папок 3 - название проекта эклипса, название проект джанго, конфиг с тем же названием в папке. 
2 папки - потому что нет проекта
1 папки не будет, потому что структура давно изменилась, а документацию читаете для старой версии

Comment: Не знаю как Eclipse создает django-проект, но предположил бы, что 1 папка - это папка проекта в eclipse (либо virtual environment). 2 папка - это папка проекта django которую вы создаете командой startproject. 3 папка - это папка приложения, которая обычно создается командой manage.py startapp <имя приложения>